# How to use an ImageButton on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, button, hyperlink

I want to link a button to this website "http://www.afl.com.au/news/2014-09-19/essendon-asada-verdict-delivered" When the user clicks the image button. I have searched on the net and can't find an exact solution.This is what I have so far

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AFLImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AFLDismissed.png" Width="480px"/>
```

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: I've tried to edit your post to remove "searched alot" and "thank you notes", but almost nothing left of the post... so I reverted my change. Please consider checking out search results for `ImageButton` like http://www.bing.com/search?q=ImageButton and at least read MSDN article so you can show what onClick handler you've tried and what you have problems with.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did, in this situation what was needed for me was Response.Redirect in code behind. I didn't think about Response.Redirect, it flew passed my thoughts.

Comment: Consider re-reading your question (especially title) - there is nothing about the fact that you even know how to handle clicks. If you've shown code that handles click and added comment "need to navigate to url (server side)" in code it would be much better question. Instead you posted spam-looking link to a site and a lot of fluffy text :(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASPX:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AFLImageButton1" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="~/Images/AFLDismissed.png" Width="480px" 
    onclick="AFLImageButton1_Click"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void AFLImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
       Response.Redirect("http://www.afl.com.au/news/2014-09-19/essendon-asada-verdict-delivered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1 ) use this code

<asp:ImageButton ID="AFLImageButton1" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="http://www.afl.com.au/news/2014-09-19/essendon-asada-verdict-delivered"  ImageUrl="~/Images/AFLDismissed.png" Width="480px"/>

2) use this code
               or
<asp:ImageButton ID="AFLImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AFLDismissed.png"  onclick="ImageButton1_Click" Width="480px"/>


cs file add this code

   protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.afl.com.au/news/2014-09-19/essendon-asada-verdict-delivered");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple anker and image tag

```
<a href="http://www.afl.com.au/news/2014-09-19/essendon-asada-verdict-delivered"><img src="Images/AFLDismissed.png"/></a>
```